# Filter and draw datatable based on column value

Tags: datatables

I'm filtering the datatable using filter method based on id which I pass. But it's not working as expected. It should filter and display the rows only that matches

```
var filterdata= thedatatable.column(0).data().filter(function( value, index) { 
        return value == grpid? true : false;

})
thedatatable.data(filterdata).draw();
```

What change's should b made

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using

```
thedatatable.columns(0).search(grpid).draw();
```